# I'm trying to Add a new Buddypress menu tab and it is not showing up

Tags: buddypress, tabs

question: I am trying to create a new sub nav item for the groups on buddy press I am using `bp_core_new_subnav_item` to do it and passing the `screen_function`, but the tab is not displaying on the group page

Any ideas where I should be looking on this?

Heres our code.

```
bp_core_new_nav_item( array(
  'name' => 'Document List',
  'slug' => 'group-document-list',
  'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->groups->slug . '/',
  'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->slug,
  'screen_function' => 'group_document_list_function_to_show_screen',
  'position' => 55 ) );

  function group_document_list_function_to_show_screen() {

   //add title and content here - last is to call the members plugin.php template
   add_action( 'bp_template_title', 'group_document_list_function_to_show_screen_title' );
   add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'group_document_list_function_to_show_screen_content' );
   bp_core_load_template( apply_filters( 'bp_core_template_plugin', 'members/single/plugins' ) );
}
function group_document_list_function_to_show_screen_title() {
    echo 'Documents for this group';
}
function group_document_list_function_to_show_screen_content() {
   display_group_document_list();
}
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question and add the code that you're using?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6719/buddypress-adding-a-new-tab-in-groups this is what we tried and it didnt work. We are thinking maybe its some plugin thats blocking the space where the tab would show up maybe?

ok trying to edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you only attempt to set up the items after BP has set up its core navigation. You can ensure this by hooking to `bp_setup_nav` with a priority higher than `10`.

Thus:

```
function bbg_setup_nav() {
    bp_core_new_subnav_item( array( 
        'name' => 'Document List',
        'slug' => 'group-document-list',
        'parent_url' => $bp->loggedin_user->domain . $bp->groups->slug . '/',
        'parent_slug' => $bp->groups->slug,
        'screen_function' => 'group_document_list_function_to_show_screen',
        'position' => 55
    ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'bbg_setup_nav', 100 );
```

Keep in mind that, as written, this code is intended to add a subnav tab to the `Groups` subnav of a *user profile*. If you want to attach it to a single group instead, you need to relativize it to groups, using a different `parent_slug` and `parent_url`:

```
// ...
'parent_slug' => bp_get_current_group_slug(),
'parent_url'  => bp_get_group_permalink( groups_get_current_group() )
// ...
```

To be honest, though, if you want to be adding subnav items to BP Groups, your best bet is to use the BP Group Extension API http://codex.buddypress.org/developer-docs/group-extension-api/. You just fill in a few methods, and all the BP-specific navigation logic is done for you. If there are methods (like `create_screen()` you're not going to use, just leave them blank.

Comment: In reviewing your original code, I realized that you used the wrong function - `bp_core_new_nav_item()` instead of `bp_core_new_subnav_item()`. The former is used for adding components to user profiles. For groups, the latter must be used. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful Boone. I am new to this website so I didnt see how to "Accept" answers or I would have before.

Comment: @BooneGorges can you include an example of how to do this using the BP Group Extension API on my post here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/223416/how-do-you-create-a-sub-navigation-menu-screen-on-a-buddypress-group-page? This is what I'm trying to do, but I figured as you suggested here, that with the group extension API I should be using that, just can't find documentation that shows how to create subnavs tabs.

Comment: @Xtremefaith The language here is confusing. The code above explains (a) how to add a *subnav* to a user's Groups nav, and (b) how to add a *nav* to a specific group. It so happens that BP implements group *nav* in the same way as a profile *subnav*. BP currently has no direct way in the API to create visual subnav items (they'd technically be sub-subnavs) in groups. See bp-templates/bp-legacy/buddypress/groups/single/admin.php and `bp_groups_admin_tabs()` to see a workaround.